# Get only part of Json object from a Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I return a response with only part of an object

```
var jason = {
"age" : "24",
"hometown" : "Missoula, MT",
"gender" : "male"
};
```

If I wanted to return a response only with the key/value pair.

```
"hometown" : "Missoula, MT"
```

Oki, I am new at this and thought I could come with a counterexample I tried the dot notation and it simply returned the Value not the key

```
var stations = [
    {id: 1, description: "London", lat: 64.1275, lon: 21.9028, observations: [2]},
    {id: 2, description: "Spain", lat: 65.6856, lon: 18.1002, observations: [1]}
];
```

If i loop and use stations[1].description i just get the value "London"

```
[
{description: "London"};
{description: "Spain"}
]
```

Comment: So just access it from the object. `jason.hometown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code loops through the object, checks if the key matches the expected key and if the value matched the expected value. If so, it `console.log()`'s it in the form `key : value`.

```js
var jason = {
"age" : "24",
"hometown" : "Missoula, MT",
"gender" : "male"
};
var key = "hometown";
var value = "Missoula, MT";

for (var tempKey in jason) {
  var obj = jason[key];
  
  if (tempKey == key && value == jason[key]) {
    console.log(key + " : " + jason[key]);
  }
}
```